# Add gesturerecognizer to UIBarButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, tweak, theos

I am trying to make Notes (default app) tweak , and wants to add gesture recognizer to **UIBarButton.**
But when I tested, UIBarButton-view seems not to recognize gesture recognizer. Could someone help me?

_shareButtonItem is a UIBarButton instance and member variable of class 'NotesDisplayController'.

```
%hook NotesDisplayController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)view {

UIBarButtonItem* hookbtn;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "_shareButtonItem", (void**)&hookbtn);

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recg = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[[hookbtn valueForKey:@"view"] addGestureRecognizer:recg];
[recg release];

%orig;



}

%new
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"longpress" message:@"longpress" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}

%end
```

Comment: Simpliest way is just add some transparent view above barbutton and add gesture recognizer to this view.

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItem` does not inherit from `UIView`, so you cannot add a gesture recognizer to it directly. Your best bet is to replace the bar button item with your own that you create using `-[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`. But since you’re jailbreaking, maybe you can traverse the toolbar’s view hierarchy and find the button that way?